# Do PC Drivers with setup.exe files not require manual installation?

Tags: drivers

Do setup.exe files for drivers enable you to NOT have to manually update/uninstall via device manager ? eg, i have  vga driver downloaded and can i just double click the setup.exe file and an Acer wizard will guide me through step by step ? And with the setup.exe type of file i dont need to uninstall the old driver via device manager ? The wizard will handle the uninstall of the old one whilst installing new one ?

Thanks for any help & Merry Xmas !

Comment: It depends on the installation but in general if you do the install using a setup.exe it can/will take care of the installation of the drivers. Additionally it may very well take care of the uninstall of an existing driver prior to installing the new one.

Answer (score 1):

The setups are mostly programmed to install drivers according to manufacturers ways. .sys (driver file) and .inf (driver information file) files are installed by setup.exe in system directory. Some setup may uninstall by deleting those files. Most of the time the update doesn't cause problem. However It is suggest  first uninstall old driver. Restart your PC to reconfigure for default settings and then install the driver setup.